# Making a mirrored design's text "readable"

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6

I am an amateur texture designer and I have been working on my own design for a vehicle from the game Arma 3. For the side of a vehicle I am texturing for, it mirrors one side to the other. So if on one side it says "POLICE" on the other side it says "ECILOP".

Is there a way that I can make the text read "POLICE" when the template is mirrored so that it reads correctly on both sides?

This is the vehicle template:

[image]

Comment: Am I right in assuming you can't change the template or use a different image for each side? And that you actually get a perfectly mirrored image on the each side, so the word is actually perfectly mirrored?

Comment: I am unsure if I can change the template, but I have been told that you can get a script to fix the mirroring so that text will appear facing the right way. eg: (How the text is read on each side of the vehicle)[Left Side] POLICE [Right Side]ECILOP -> to -> [Left Side] POLICE [Right Side] POLICE

Comment: Flip the uv map

Comment: Flipping the uv map will affect the whole texture, will it not?

Answer (score 3):

If you have to use the same image for both sides and one is being mirrored what you want is an ambigram.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambigram)

> An ambigram is a word, art form or other symbolic representation whose elements retain meaning when viewed or interpreted from a different direction, perspective, or orientation.

[image]
[image]

There are plenty of online generators and tutorials on creating ambigrams. Most I've seen work with a 180 degree rotational symmetry, but what you want is mirrored symmetry, so keep that in mind.

Edit: This is something I came up with very quickly, not sure how well it works for your situation as I'm not sure in what context/size etc people will be seeing this, but it gives you an idea of what you can do:

[image]

This is what it looks like on the texture - it reads exactly the same when flipped:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I have tried this and unfortunately it does not work, all it does is mirror, the ambigram over.

Comment: but thats the whole point of an ambigram... it's something that reads the same when mirrored. If it doesn't read correctly, you're using the wrong type of symmetry.

Comment: @Michael.C Have a look at my update, see if that's something that could work for you.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but it simply displays the picture, reversed (so the same). It essentially makes the texture double sided and displays the other side eg.   (Texture ->)   Side a|Side b So side a is the texture I have designed and side b is a reflection that appears on the other side of the vehicle, and on that side all the text is backwards. I have been told there is a way to fix this but I am unaware, I am unsure on how to edit the template so the chances that I COULD DO THAT is nil. ANY other help is appreciated at this point ;) ### My apologies for the late reply

Comment: I don't understand. The whole point of the ambigram is that it _is exactly the same_ reversed. If you look at it in the mirror you will see exactly the same thing, which is exactly what is happening if your texture is using one image for both sides of the car.

Comment: I wonder if @Michael.C is mirroring on the horizontal axis which may render the mirrored image unreadable. The solution provided by CAI is to the point, especially when mirrored on the vertical axis. There are not many words that will read the same when mirrored in all directions, like OXO. Or, am I totally misunderstanding the question?

Comment: @Michael.C I've just been reading up on the arma 3 textures and the page [here](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=355422015) specifically talks about mirroring, so what I suggested is exactly what you need and will work.

Comment: I'm assuming the problem you had was from using an ambigram with rotational symmetry - like 99% of the ambigram generators and tutorials I can find use.

Comment: @ACEkin That is what is happening, you do understand what happening

Comment: @CAI I have read that tutorial prior to writing this forum as I have been assured that there is a way to fix this, although I am unsure if it is via; Changing the template; Making a script to fix how it mirrors; or Adding text separately- through a script maybe? 

Changing the template seems the most likely but I am unsure on how to do this?

Comment: @Michael.C Other than using a different template (which is a completely different ballpark to just changing textures) there's no **other** way to get around this. You've only got one static image and a static image is just that, a static image, theres no way to change it. What i suggested *does work*.

Comment: ..and what ACEkin said is correct **if** it was mirroring on the horizontal axis.. but that's not what's happening - it's a car - if it was mirrored on the horizontal axis the wheels would be in the air on one side.